# C# Primer or example on working with files on a granular level

Tags: c#, compression

Can someone provide an example or primer on working with files on a granular level with C#. Let's assume that I want to build a new program to compress and zip files. Can I write a program like this, with C#, that gets down to the bits & bytes level?

Comment: Of course, though I'd probably use a compression library rather than rolling your own. See [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_members.aspx) for file access and [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) for compression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can surely read files byte by byte by using [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)-class and the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28VS.80%29.aspx)-class. [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader_properties.aspx) is even more granular. Having the bytes you will have the possibilty to work on bit-base with the bit-operators (|, &, <<, >>).

Examples can be found at the posted links.

P.S: You could use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) or the Compression classes of [.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) to compress files.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a good tutorial but [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4b8basy.aspx) is a good place to start for reading on the "bits & bytes" level

Answer (score 0):

You can download the free #ziplib library including C# source code here:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

That should show you how to zip files at least.